# HtmlAgility - Save parsing to a string

Tags: c#, parsing, html-parsing

Just tried using the HtmlAgility Pack for the first time and have a problem.

First I load in from a string variable.

```
string NewsText = dr["Message"].ToString();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(NewsText);
//doing my stuff...
```

Then I want to save my changes in the string NewsText. How do I do that? htmlDoc.toString() didnt work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You're looking for `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml`.