# How to save html doc in to a string?

Tags: c#, data-conversion, dom

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.Load(yourhtml);
    doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

How to save this into an string instead of Console.Out

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183385/get-whole-html-document-as-string

Comment: Why bother with a `HtmlDocument` at all when you have the HTML in a string already?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
string s = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

or

```
var sw = new StringWriter();
doc.Save(sw);
var s = sw.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
string  html = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string variableName = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

OuterHTML will have the Entire HTML..

```
string s = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using this:

```
var str = File.ReadAllText(yourHtml);
```

It will read your html document to string without initializing HtmlDocument object. Is `yourHtml`really a html or just a path? HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument does not contain Load method accepting html.

Answer (score 0):

```
   HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
   // call one of the doc.LoadXXX() functions
   Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
```