# Print HtmlDocument to metro app textbox c#

Tags: c#, html, microsoft-metro

I'm new to this Windows Metro stuff and I am trying to make a application that grab a html page from the web and fills some fields in the app.

Right now I'm just trying to figure out how to grab a page and send pure HTML to a textbox.

I've setted up a button (that runs the next function once clicked) and a textbox to display the information.

The function executed by the button is this:

```
private void fetch_websites(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String url = "http://www.google.com/";
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(url);
    this.content_block.Text = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
}
```

The problem is that the displayed information is not the Html code but the "url" string.

(I've seen this code in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183385/get-whole-html-document-as-string) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599012/html-agility-pack-htmldocument-show-all-html))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LoadHtml method takes the `html` content to parse. It doesn't automatically loads the **url**. Use HtmlAgilityPack's  HtmlWeb class or HttpClient / WebClient / HttpWebRequest classes  to get the page from your url.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
    private async void fetch_websites(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String url = "http://www.google.com/";
        HtmlWeb page = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = await page.LoadFromWebAsync(url);
        //doc.LoadHtml(url);
        this.content_block.Text = doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
    }
```